# Images not showing in Vue-cli webpack template

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am having a few issues with my vue-cli app.

this app has been made using the webpack template. On my App.vue I am using a component where the image loads fine, but for every component rendered by the view router, the images dont show despite the file path being exactly the same as the image used on the Header.vue file.

when I run:

```
npm run dev
```

the image i am referencing on the Header.vue get put on the static folder which works fine, but that is the only image that works which is quite strange.

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>bkchat_proto1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/mbh1drh.css">
    <style>
    body {
      background-color:#D5DDE5;
    }

    .section {
      background-color:#fff !important;
      padding:0.5em;
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width:100% !important;
    }

    .font1 {
      font-family: "anzeigen-grotesk",sans-serif;
    }
    .font2 {
      font-family: "prohibition",sans-serif;
    }
    .font3 {
      font-family: "rift-soft";
    }

    .font4 {
      font-family: "industry-inc-base";
    }
    .postImg {
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      min-width:inherit;
      height:15em;
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .postImg {
        min-height:300px;
      }
     }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <Header></Header>
    <div class="row">
      <router-view></router-view>
      <Aside></Aside>
    </div>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Aside from './components/Aside';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  },
  components: {
    'Header':Header,
    'Aside':Aside,
    'Footer':Footer
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Header.vue file:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <header class="header_img">
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="link in navLinks">
          <a :href="link.url" class="font3"> {{link.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      navLinks:[
        {
          name:'home',
          url:'/'
        },
        {
          name:'contact',
          url:'/contact'
        },
        {
          name:'cast members',
          url:'/cast_members'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
.header_img {
  background-image: url('../assets/img/header.jpg');
  background-size:contain;
  height:20em;
  width:100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  background-color:#0882FF;
  width:90% !important;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px black
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color:#FFC611;
}
</style>
```

Footer.vue file:

```
<template lang="html">
  <footer class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h3 class="font2"><span>B</span><span class="flip">K</span>CHAT</h3>
    </div>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
  footer {
    margin-top:3em;
    background-color:#262624;
    max-height:300px;
  }
  .flip {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    position:relative;
  }

  footer h3 {
    color:white;
  }
</style>
```

Aside.vue:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <aside class="section">
      <label for="search" class="font2">SEARCH</label>
      <input type="search" name="search" value="" placeholder="Look for something...">
      <hr>
      <div class="social_icons">
        <h5 class="font2">{{social_msg}}</h5>
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-snapchat-ghost fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i>
      </div>

    </aside>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      social_media:[
        {
          name:'',
          link:'',
          icon:''
        }
      ],
      social_msg:'FOLLOW US'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
  svg {
    display: block !important;
    margin:1em auto 1em auto;
  }
  .social_icons {
    padding:1em;
  }
  h5, svg{
    text-align:center;
  }

  input[type="search"] {
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    margin-left:0.5em;
  }

  input[type="search"]:focus {
    outline:none;
  }
</style>
```

The file I am having issues with images with:

Main.vue:

```
<template lang="html">
  <section class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="section">
      <h1 class="font1">{{welcome_title}}</h1>
      <p>{{welcome_msg}}</p>
      <hr>
      <h1 class="font2">{{news_title}}</h1>

      <div class="news_post" v-for="news in news_post">

        <div v-if="news.img !== '' " class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="postImg" v-bind:style="{'background-image': 'url('+ news.img +')'}"></div>

        </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
            <h2 class="font1">{{news.title}}</h2>
            <p class="content">{{news.content}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div v-else class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="font1">{{news.title}}</h2>
            <p class="content">{{news.content}}</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>  <!-- end of for -->
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import Aside from './Aside';

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      welcome_title:'Welcome to BkChat LDN!',
      welcome_msg:'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
      news_title:'NEWS',
      news_post:[
        {
          title:'Latest news from BkChat:',
          img:'',
          content:'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.',
          id:'1',
          date:''
        },
        {
          title:'Latest news from BkChat:',
          img:'../assets/img/img1.jpg',
          content:'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.',
          id:'1',
          date:''
        },
        {
          title:'Latest news from BkChat:',
          img:'',
          content:'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.',
          id:'1',
          date:''
        }
      ]
    }
  }// end of data
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
  .content,.news_post {
    margin:1em;
  }
  .news_post > .row > div > h2{
    margin-left: 0.5em;
  }
</style>
```

router/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Contact from '../components/Contact.vue'
import Main from '../components/Main.vue'
import CastMembers from '../components/castMembers.vue'


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {path:'/', component:Main},
    {path:'/contact', component:Contact},
    {path:'/cast_members', component:CastMembers}],
  mode:'history'
})
```

Comment: You will have better chance of showing the image if you store in inside your `static/` folder that comes with the installation

Comment: Hey samayo thanks! it worked. But I am just curious, Is there a more effecient to refference images on a vue-cli app? I just saw this thing online about alias but I dont really understand how that works? do you know anything about it?

Comment: The alias you are referring to might be the one used to short-reference a module. So, when you import local component, instead of doing 
endless `../../../../something.vue` to import a component, you can create an alias to your src files in your webpack config and just use `@/something.vue` -- other than that, I would have to read it only. I can't say it exists ... maybe a link?